# Canyons and stuff

Tags: riddle, geography

This turned out pretty easy, but enjoy anyway.

> The grandest of canyons is found within me;
>   few can match my nature's diversity.
>
> The continent's largest metropolis I boast,
>   along with a long stretch of Pacific coast.
>
> Beside me a massive saltwater gulf lies
>   and I possess some Caribbean isles.
>
> I think that these clues are sufficient, mates.
>   Tell me the name of these united states?

Looking for the name of a country.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer is:

> United Mexican States

The grandest of canyons is found within me;

> I think we are talking about the Copper Canyon

few can match my nature's diversity.

> The nature of Mexico is very diverse

The continent's largest metropolis I boast,

> Mexico city is the largest metropolis in North America

along with a long stretch of Pacific coast.

Beside me a massive saltwater gulf lies
and I possess some Caribbean isles.

> And it matches all the above due to its location

And, of course, all the above might probably apply to:

> the USA but then it would have been too simple

Comment: Told you it'd be easy :)